# GPG armor output ending with == followed by four characters

Tags: gnupg

Is there a reason why GPG output always ends with `==` followed by 4-characters?

Here are the last few lines of my GPG public key:

```
...
OOr8IiqHUQhVk8JosOWrUMbkIuaQCngYloRLkaxAtBpQcDO3iAEWF+gGP6Du3yU4
zkfn0rmC6YUuqJGiRb6BeFxJqFCXvr5WmX87k3DLAyBTcG4Pw1sioU64h55wOg2S
v0D46sdWlvtAAbfN5YI7zqzCoBaorko2Aacq5gM4mJzad9uw52064Tqqvz+FE/Os
JaTXjzJz7Fr1vZQDJMHFmKSquFqxivL8nVwOADuBDJRl6Q1a2iMXHqiv79M9WAQX
YKvkP4WGz6R4eqdRAmzmSU3qjSw0odvkbzS8ziuMzao02dO37VcZZ4sOHyEwRa9c
rBvrdj2W2YM4+IVmm2/LQdZbuVovft/Uad7UQymMeJr2ny8/6xt8QZwQiz51RDs=
=QLDn
```

Here are the last few lines of a random file encrypted by me with GPG:

```
...
ao3y/ppJ2eOwh8VAAyvCCX38Bg0ehs8PFrdpZ6zLzHJP3oj+O38zEErx6fP35jR6
XIJ3w9DilXk0IXGDN5Bv2GfLg3sQPJIYl5lqbMS3jzL8j/SL+/9P7WR6oNkoz2pc
BtFmlTuMkc2MCpe67qTD0TlEzPfFuhFxBrxIP4/bODgRdB/9aPDOPCH/gEIqlyAC
yq0qNOcs9tQSMAWZI6VwsHO0WaQ8azhVf53w5v4HbQn/kU/OfzyuoE8AN6xYO9vS
XgE8IiHT9XnDyiJkaNMHHbWNdK86Tbg5LSzdtC2gEWMNpYe7jwlYaCfiri5SJ1u0
WJEg7vwwiuNF/mN00a1B3aoK/0LB17E5GfeAbRbCLnfhTwFF9x7D9rdj5MgMP0E=
=qtjG
```

and here is a random file from a [source](http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/gpg/gpg-com-4.htm):

```
wBC3poSYT+l63wNO73CDhx4VbpOzLgzbyNB6O67iuiQm2D9hLwk8L4YPOoMlfwyM
kUmsZUX709sMBHZN/9aniaVBsLxszHw9xu5OuSz/lHkckplcwb94XDLh1KGGO+1Q
LzbpFYPqe3BANLK5xxlQAAti/uk0XYltVJfUOCzyxl282X3Tp/77FtiGGb8RI1HY
hslojkAQa9gK1+f44Y8LwHH5k7fQr+Q+luqP7inoEQWbpWW4hu80Wkafv/bzI/xu
Z1qGcEVcJGJPP7QwQWUp53FbZuIq742CoxNklwvlnjhEaXa5rG2dmHUREawVzz+q
M8RkPBZIBge0SVY=
=WznL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public keys you're describing are encoded as per [RFC 4880 §6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6):

> OpenPGP's Radix-64 encoding is composed of **two parts: a base64
> encoding of the binary data and a checksum**.  The base64 encoding is
> identical to the MIME base64 content-transfer-encoding [RFC2045].
>
> The checksum is a 24-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) converted to
> four characters of radix-64 encoding by the same MIME base64
> transformation, preceded by an equal sign (=).

Base64 encoding is always padded with 0-3 '=' characters at the end; OpenPGP adds another '=' and follows it with 4 characters of checksum.

Since the checksum is always 4 characters, and Base64 pads to reach a multiple of 4, there is never a need for '=' padding after the checksum.